# How to connect VPN PPTP in MacOS with Mojave?

Tags: macos, operating-system, vpn, macos-mojave, pptp

I need to connect to a VPN network using the PPTP protocol.
I know that Apple no longer supports the protocol because it is insecure. But I can not force my client to change the infrastructure.

I am using this following setting in my Mojave 10.14.4 operating system:

```
sudo touch /etc/ppp/peers/vpn.pplware
```

```
plugin PPTP.ppp
noauth
# logfile /tmp/ppp.log
remoteaddress "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
user "xxxxxx"
password "xxxxxxxx"
redialcount 1
redialtimer 5
idle 1800
# mru 1368
# mtu 1368
receive-all
novj 0:0
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
# noauth
refuse-eap
refuse-pap
refuse-chap-md5
hide-password
mppe-stateless
mppe-128
# require-mppe-128
looplocal
nodetach
# ms-dns 8.8.8.8
usepeerdns
# ipparam gwvpn
defaultroute
debug
```

```
sudo pppd call vpn.pplware
```

and i get return this message:

```
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : PPTP connecting to server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : PPTP connection established.
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : PPTP set port-mapping for en0, interface: 5, protocol: 0, privatePort: 0
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : using link 0
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : Using interface ppp0
Mon Jun 10 18:07:03 2019 : Connect: ppp0 <--> socket[34:17]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1450> <magic 0x1dc9c59c>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x46f715e9> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : lcp_reqci: returning CONFACK.
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <auth chap MS-v2> <mru 1450> <magic 0x1dc9c59c>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <magic 0x46f715e9>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <magic 0x46f715e9>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <3f97bcd12af46ab9d0a135b28e397ac4>, name = "xxxxxx"]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <caa253b0c1d7e78d91dc061a46c8400b0000000000000000185c946143621c489c08f2a63532b3f2c2a0c0bb896916a600>, name = "xxxxxx"]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 "S=D28F3FC4E46AB51B37497DF2516A96B8A00B1D2C"]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [IPCP TermAck id=0x1]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [proto=0x8281] 01 01 00 04
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : Unsupported protocol 0x8281 received
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 82 81 01 01 00 04]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [proto=0x8031] 01 01 00 0c 03 03 01 08 03 01 09 02
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : Unsupported protocol 'Bridging NCP' (0x8031) received
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP ProtRej id=0x4 80 31 01 01 00 0c 03 03 01 08 03 01 09 02]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [CCP ConfReq id=0x1]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [CCP ConfAck id=0x1]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : rcvd [CCP ConfRej id=0x1 <mppe +H -M +S -L -D -C>]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : MPPE required but peer refused
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : sent [LCP TermReq id=0x5 "MPPE required but peer refused"]
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : Connection terminated.
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : PPTP disconnecting...
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : PPTP clearing port-mapping for en0
Mon Jun 10 18:07:04 2019 : PPTP disconnected
```